# UI Bootstrap with Flot causing misaligned ticks

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap, flot

I'm working on an Angular web-app with UI Bootstrap and have run into a problem with the y-tick label alignment in flot charts using UI tabs.

With standard bootstrap tabs, the plots match inside and outside the tabset:
http://jsfiddle.net/TDwGF/614/

However, with UI Bootstrap's `tabset`, we find that the y-tick labels overlap with the plot:
http://jsfiddle.net/TDwGF/615/

In playing with different approaches in building the flot directive, I can create a plot where only half of the y-tick labels are misaligned (I was not able to reproduce this well in a minimal example, however).

[image: Misaligned y-axis ticks]

I cannot find any inherited css modifications that would cause these issues, and I haven't met with any luck in going through the tabs directive source code.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: While I still do not have a fix for this, it's worth noting that this issue is not present when using angular-strap tabs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I remember that something similar had already happened with me while working with [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/).

The root cause of the misalignment is probably the browser dynamic rendering timing restraining the canvas/svg container space.

---

To workaround this kind of issue, just wrap the plot creation with a timeout to render it on next digest cycle:

```
App.directive('chart', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            var data = scope[attrs.ngModel];
            setTimeout(function(){
                $.plot(elem, data, {});
                scope.$apply();
            }, 0);
        }
    };
});
```

[See working `setTimeout` fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/TDwGF/664/)

---

Anternatively you could inject angular `$timeout`, so it already calls `scope.$apply()` for you:

```
App.directive('chart', ['$timeout', function($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            var data = scope[attrs.ngModel];
            $timeout(function() {
                $.plot(elem, data, {});
            }, 0);
        }
    };
}]);
```

[See working `$timeout` fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/TDwGF/665/)

Comment: Thank you for sharing the solution.  I certainly would not have thought of that.